# Add all the bands of Landsat in Google Earth Engine?

Tags: google-earth-engine, landsat, ndvi

I have only NDVI band and I want to add all the bands for unsupervised classification.

My code:

```
var dataset1=ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI').filterDate('2000-01-01','2000-12- 
 31');
var NDVI= dataset1.select('NDVI');
var ndvimean=NDVI.reduce(ee.Reducer.mean());
var ndviclip=ndvimean.clip(poi);
var visparam={
  min: 0.0,
  max: 1.0,
  palette: [
 'FFFFFF', 'CE7E45', 'DF923D', 'F1B555', 'FCD163', '99B718', '74A901',
 '66A000', '529400', '3E8601', '207401', '056201', '004C00', '023B01',
 '012E01', '011D01', '011301'
 ]
};
Map.addLayer(ndviclip,visparam,'NDVI',0);
```

Answer (score 1):

Your post is very short on detail. You are using the `LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_32DAY_NDVI` collection, which only contain NDVI. If you need all Landsat bands, you need to use a different collection. Which one to use depends on what time period you need, and if you want surface corrected imagery or not. One of these collections could be a good place to start:

- `LANDSAT/LT05/C01/T1_SR`
- `LANDSAT/LE07/C01/T1_SR`
- `LANDSAT/LC08/C01/T1_SR`

To find other collections, or read up on the ones above, go to the code editor and enter `landsat` in the `Search places and datasets...` search box. The [classification docs](https://developers.google.com/earth-engine/classification) contains an example how to create a cloud free mosaic to use in a classification.

Comment: sir i wantto test my unsupervised classification